# Flutter Execute Http request on startup using FutureBuilder not working

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the homepage code of the app I'm currently developing and I have to get all data from API. Therefore I've come up `_getLatest` that gets the data from the URL which is a list of maps and the data goes into `_latest`. And I implemented the future builder based on [Flutter: Execute a function on Startup - wait for HTTP response parser to extract image URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250137/flutter-execute-a-function-on-startup-wait-for-http-response-parser-to-extrac) but things are not quite done.

First of all there are two blue underlines: 1. `Future<String> _getLatest() async {` says
**This function has a return type of 'FutureOr', but doesn't end with a return statement.** 2. `builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {` says **This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement.**

And the main problem is the homepage is that `snapshot.connectionState` doesn't change to done state so it's loading data eternally. And I'm pretty sure it's because of the code not the URL, the API works fine.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:kzstats/common/AppBar.dart';
import 'package:kzstats/common/Drawer.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  final String currentPage = 'KZStats';
  var _latest = [];

  Future<String> _getLatest() async {
    var url =
        'https://kztimerglobal.com/api/v2.0/records/top/recent?stage=0&tickrate=128&modes_list_string=kz_timer&limit=3';
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var result;
    try {
      var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      var response = await request.close();
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        var json = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        var data = jsonDecode(json);
        result = data;
      } else {}
    } catch (exception) {}

    setState(() {
      _latest = result;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: HomepageAppBar(currentPage),
      drawer: HomepageDrawer(),
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _getLatest(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 3,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new Card(
                  elevation: 5.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Text('${_latest[index]}'),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                    child: Text('Loading data from API...'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Builder(builder: (builderContext) {
        return FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
          _getLatest();
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have done some wrong things,

- if you are using `FutureBuilder` you can use a snapshot inside it so no need for `_latest` variable.
- you can also use `http` package for easily requesting data.
- inside your `_getLatest()` function you didn't returned the value and also it was not `String`.
- also you can use Model class for easily assessing data after fetching json.

For your Problem my solution is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
    

    
  final String currentPage = 'KZStats';

  Future<List<KzTimer>> _getLatest() async {
    var url =
        'https://kztimerglobal.com/api/v2.0/records/top/recent?stage=0&tickrate=128&modes_list_string=kz_timer&limit=3';
    
    List<KzTimer> result;
    
    try {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      
      
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        
        
         result = kzTimerFromJson(response.body);
        
      } else {
          print('Something went wrong!');
      }
    } catch (exception) {}

    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<KzTimer>>(
        future: _getLatest(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<KzTimer>> snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData ?
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 3,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new Card(
                  elevation: 5.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Text('${snapshot.data[index].playerName}'),
                  //_latest[index].playerName
                );
              },
            ) :
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                    child: Text('Loading data from API...'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ) ;
          
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Builder(builder: (builderContext) {
        return FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
          _getLatest();
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Method to convert the response data to your model class data

```
List<KzTimer> kzTimerFromJson(String str) => List<KzTimer>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => KzTimer.fromJson(x)));
```

Model class

```
class KzTimer {
    KzTimer({
        this.id,
        this.steamid64,
        this.playerName,
        this.steamId,
        this.serverId,
        this.mapId,
        this.stage,
        this.mode,
        this.tickrate,
        this.time,
        this.teleports,
        this.createdOn,
        this.updatedOn,
        this.updatedBy,
        this.place,
        this.top100,
        this.top100Overall,
        this.serverName,
        this.mapName,
        this.points,
        this.recordFilterId,
        this.replayId,
    });

    int id;
    String steamid64;
    String playerName;
    String steamId;
    int serverId;
    int mapId;
    int stage;
    String mode;
    int tickrate;
    double time;
    int teleports;
    DateTime createdOn;
    DateTime updatedOn;
    int updatedBy;
    int place;
    int top100;
    int top100Overall;
    String serverName;
    String mapName;
    int points;
    int recordFilterId;
    int replayId;

    factory KzTimer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => KzTimer(
        id: json["id"],
        steamid64: json["steamid64"],
        playerName: json["player_name"],
        steamId: json["steam_id"],
        serverId: json["server_id"],
        mapId: json["map_id"],
        stage: json["stage"],
        mode: json["mode"],
        tickrate: json["tickrate"],
        time: json["time"].toDouble(),
        teleports: json["teleports"],
        createdOn: DateTime.parse(json["created_on"]),
        updatedOn: DateTime.parse(json["updated_on"]),
        updatedBy: json["updated_by"],
        place: json["place"],
        top100: json["top_100"],
        top100Overall: json["top_100_overall"],
        serverName: json["server_name"],
        mapName: json["map_name"],
        points: json["points"],
        recordFilterId: json["record_filter_id"],
        replayId: json["replay_id"],
    );
}
```

Comment: You can check live preview at https://codeapprun.io/pratik/widget/qqrRRtDRLQ

Comment: also use this site to convert your json responses to data class https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: Take my knees I've got no words but thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Change return type by: `Future<void>`. You are returning nothing.
2. You have an `if` and an `else if` but you still need the default case when both conditions are `false`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply 2 worked! But for 1 if I change the return type to Future<void>, there will be an exception at `future: _getLatest(),` saying **type 'Future<void>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String>?** located within the builder method.

Comment: you have use FutureBuilder<String> and AsyncSnapshot<String> so you are getting that error

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:kzstats/common/AppBar.dart';
import 'package:kzstats/common/Drawer.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  final String currentPage = 'KZStats';
  var _latest = [];

  Future<String> _getLatest() async {
    var url =
        'https://kztimerglobal.com/api/v2.0/records/top/recent?stage=0&tickrate=128&modes_list_string=kz_timer&limit=3';
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var result;
    try {
      var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      var response = await request.close();
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        var json = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        var data = jsonDecode(json);
        result = data;
      } else {}
    } catch (exception) {}

    setState(() {
      _latest = result;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: HomepageAppBar(currentPage),
      drawer: HomepageDrawer(),
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _getLatest(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 3,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new Card(
                  elevation: 5.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Text('${_latest[index]}'),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                    child: Text('Loading data from API...'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Builder(builder: (builderContext) {
        return FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () => 
          _getLatest;
        
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

The Correct Version of Your Code

Comment: I changed it but it's still not working. I just tested the code by replacing the whole FutureBuilder into `Container(child: Text('$_latest'),),` and _latest has gotten the data from API so there's gotta be something wrong with my FutureBuilder but not the _getLatest